# awaitUninterruptibly in netty

Tags: netty

I thought awaitUninterruptibly means block code execution until operation complete, but seems not like that:

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    ChannelFuture f = e.getChannel().close();
    f.awaitUninterruptibly(); // ok, not netty i/o thread, I use a Execution Handler
    System.out.println("bbb " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    System.out.println("aaa " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

I found "bbb" is execute before "aaa", If I turn to debug mode and goes line by line, "aaa" is before "bbb" because code execution has been slow down. Did I misunderstand awaitUninterruptibly?

await only effect on current thread, but using ExectionHandler or a thread pool worker threads, the close might executed by another thread, so await is useless. It requires adding ChannelFutureListener to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The I/O worker thread signals the future as soon as the channel is closed and then goes on to process the callbacks. In this case your thread pool thread is being rescheduled before the I/O worker is able to fire the associated disconnected, unbound and closed, events. When you run through the debugger you're changing the way the threads are scheduled.

Generally future's are used to determine when the requested operation has completed, not that any other operations that may be triggered by the operation completing have also completed.

Take a look at https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioWorker.java specifically the void close(NioSocketChannel channel, ChannelFuture future) method for the exact logic.

Comment: Is there any way to do what I want to? Seems hard if using execution handler

Comment: What type of executor are you passing to your execution handler. IN retrospect I'm a little surprised that you saw "aaa" before "bbb" in debug mode if you're using OrderMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor as you shouldn't see further events until messageReceived has returned. Are the two methods shown above in the same upstream handler? Also, can you explain why you need to see channelDisconnected before messageReceived returns?

Comment: yes, I am using OrderMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor, 2 methods belong to one Handler which below execution handler in pipeline.

Comment: When a account has been log on twice, I need kick the former one offline, but before close former's channel, I need to save it's data. So I hope codes in channelDisconnected could be executed complete before codes in messageReceived which handle next one log on. Any suggest? In netty doc, the typical way seems should be make log on to a independent handler and put it above execution handler

Comment: That's why "aaa" before "bbb" in debug, because messageReceived called and channelDisconnected called belong to distinct handler object. I thought you ask whether or not belong to one handler class, sorry

Comment: If you really want to structure it in that way you could override closeRequested on SimpleDownstreamChannelHandler. This would allow you to save your state as part of the closing process. Then, when the future completes, your state will have been saved. Whether this is the best approach depends on your application. I would suggest that you call close and wait on the future in a handler above the thread pool. Generally I would be very cautious about blocking an I/O thread in any circumstance.

Comment: Thanks. I put save code in override channelDisconnected because it works normal offline also. I found put log on code above thread pool will be more difficult to control, that even don't guarantee event process sequence. If 2 people log on same account at same time, that will be worse. Finally I found that ChannelFutureListener can do this, but requires you re-arrange code